# Google Chrome issuing Head Request to random domains

Tags: google-chrome, head

Today I was investigating on something with Fiddler, when I noticed that, when I launch Google Chrome, I have always 3 HEAD requests to some domains which seem to be randomly chosen.

Here is a sample :

```
HEAD http://fkgrekxzgo/ HTTP/1.1
Host: fkgrekxzgo
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
```

Do you have any idea of why Google Chrome behaves this way ?

Thanks guys

Comment: Observed the same with fiddler while trying to troubleshoot what I think is a malware. In any case was wondering why it was not occurring with mozilla and IE but was occuring with chrome. Thanks for the confirmation (that its not just me!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Chrome checking to see if your ISP converts non-resolving domains into your.isp.com/search?q=randomnonresolvingdomain

See https://mikewest.org/2012/02/chrome-connects-to-three-random-domains-at-startup

Comment: Your link - it is dead

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm seems unusable with forward proxy servers. Browser definitely asks for random page and proxy definitely returns some page -- error (50x), masked error (50x or 40x) or nice "you are lost" page with HTTP code 200 .